# app does not work when Run in Flutter in Android Studio is pressed

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, device-manager, virtual-device-manager

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-2.2.1/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:45:41: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
  String get packageRoot => io.Platform.packageRoot;
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1102

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I received this error when I tried to run my flutter app on an emulator in android-studio. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

It worked but by  using

dependencies:

```
platform: ^3.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Platform.packageRoot member variable now has been removed in the platform
plugin. All you need to do is override dependency to the previous version.

```
dependency_overrides:
  platform: 2.2.0
```